# Когда v8 падает с сообщением Very long string

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Пожскажите, в каких случаях приложение под nodejs падает с сообщениям **Very long string**. Я подозреваю, что превышаются какие-то лимиты по памяти, но какие и где их изменить. Вот примерный вывод при этом:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[29305:0x3c03570]  1035866 ms: Mark-sweep 17592186044395.8 (49.0) -> 17592186044395.8 (20.5) MB, 18.1 / 0.0 ms  last resort 
[29305:0x3c03570]  1035884 ms: Mark-sweep 17592186044395.8 (20.5) -> 17592186044395.8 (20.5) MB, 17.9 / 0.0 ms  last resort 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x231a63c1ba79 <JS Object>
    1: exec(this=0x14668f1ef8d9 <JS RegExp>,0x3f857f9eb3a1 <Very long string[2380557]>)
    2: firstchar(aka firstchar) [node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:~174] [pc=0x2ff28c23b6cb](this=0x231a63c02241 <undefined>,str=0x3f857f9eb3a1 <Very long string[2380557]>)
    3: parse(aka parse) [node_mod...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x141357c [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 6: v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 7: v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpExec(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::RegExpMatchInfo>) [node]
 8: v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Exec(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::RegExpMatchInfo>) [node]
 9: v8::internal::Runtime_RegExpExec(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
10: 0x2ff28be040bd
Aborted (core dumped)
error Command failed with exit code 134.
```

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/14402

Comment: Да, проблема была в nodejs **8.1** В **8.5** все нормально.